# Wall how prevent the formation of the gaps

Tags: html, css

I creating wall and i have problem.

Better to show it in the picture:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1uVA3PF.png]

Question is: how can I prevent the formation of the gaps?

[image: Image: [http://i.imgur.com/6EvVji5.png][2]]

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="shoot">...</div>
   <div class="shoot">...</div>
   <div class="shoot">...</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper{
    width: 769px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.shoot{
    width: 370px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 7px;
}
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 769px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.shoot{
  width: 370px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 7px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.clear-div{
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="shoot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
  <div class="shoot">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tristique id justo ac         varius. In massa velit, malesuada nec augue at, consectetur pulvinar dolor.
  </div>
  <div class="shoot">In massa velit, malesuada nec augue at.</div>
  <div class="clear-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a fiddle (google "new fiddle") to demo what you have so far and explain what you want.  Include CSS and HTML.

Comment: I hope it will be enough.

Comment: The reason I suggested the fiddle is that the community can then help you debug it interactively.  I don't think this can be done with what you posted - the issue is clear (which is good), but we don't have a way to help you.

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/32azzrwb/. I thought code snippet is enough.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like the Masonry plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @StephanMuller, only if he's using jQuery, if javascript at all

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to enclose the left part in a div, and set that containing div to have `float:left` and set the right div to have `float:right`. If you wanted to put multiple items on the right, you could just enclose all the right `div`s into a container and set `float:right` on that. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/32azzrwb/2/

Comment: It works, but how to solve it with dynamic content? That's why I tried to keep "shoot" the same.